# PlugnMeet - Error: could not establish pc connection

Tags: reactjs, typescript, plugins, videocall

I have a problem when i use plugnMeet. When i try to enter a video call after clicking the microphone it gives me this error:

> could not establish pc connection.

I have tried the find from internet or plugnMeet forum if the problem is solved but there is not a concrete solution. In documentation it suggest me as

```
--config "/app/livekit.yaml" --dev --node-ip YOUR_IP_HERE  -- https://www.plugnmeet.org/docs/developer-guide/setup-development/
```

However, even though i do as it is indicated in documentation the problem persist. Does anyone has a idea what can i do to resolve the problem?

I use ubuntu version 22.04.

I tried to enter the main page of the ideo call. In my code when i comment the part `await this._room.connect(this.url, this.token);` and try to enter it makes me enter to the main page but as soon as i enter i have to uncomment this part. In this way it works and after entering first time i can enter always without problem. However, it is not a correct way. First time without commenting this part how it is possible to manage this problem.

```
constructor(
  livekitInfo: LivekitInfo,
  errorState: Dispatch<IErrorPageProps>,
  roomConnectionStatusState: Dispatch<ConnectionStatus>,
) {
  super();
  this.token = livekitInfo.token;
  this.url = livekitInfo.livekit_host;
  this.enabledE2EE = livekitInfo.enabledE2EE;

  this.errorState = errorState;
  this.roomConnectionStatusState = roomConnectionStatusState;
  this._e2eeKeyProvider = new ExternalE2EEKeyProvider();

  this.handleParticipant = new HandleParticipants(this);
  this.handleMediaTracks = new HandleMediaTracks(this);
  this.handleDataMessages = new HandleDataMessages(this);
  this.handleRoomMetadata = new HandleRoomMetadata(this);
  this.handleActiveSpeakers = new HandleActiveSpeakers(this);

  this.roomConnectionStatusState('connecting');
  // clean session data
  sessionStorage.clear();
  // configure room
  this._room = this.configureRoom();
  // finally connect
  this.connect();
 }




private connect = async () => {
  try {
    console.log('try to connect')
    await this._room.connect(this.url, this.token);
    // we'll prepare our information
    console.log('try to update session')
    await this.updateSession();
    console.log('try to initiateParticipants')
    await this.initiateParticipants();
    // open websocket
    openWebsocketConnection();
    // finally
    this.roomConnectionStatusState('connected');
    // start token renew interval
    this.startTokenRenewInterval();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    this.roomConnectionStatusState('error');
    this.errorState({
      title: 'Error',
      text: String(error),
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Moreover, in network i don't have an error but I have the following error in my console:

ConnectLivekit.ts:42 Error: could not establish pc connection
    at livekit-client.esm.mjs:16953:1